# Cron that executes every 5min between 6PM and 8PM during weekdays

Tags: c#, cron, azure-functions

I wanted to build a cron expression for Azure function timer triggers that executes every 5 minutes interval between 6pm and 11pm during weekdays only.

This is for azure function timer triggered.

Comment: Got the answer

TimerTrigger("0 */5 18-23 * * 1-5")

From https://codehollow.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/

Comment: who upvotes these? whats the significance of this question and answer? this question was probably asked in this form or the other thousands of times. there are many web sites with cron cheat sheats\examples\calculators.

Comment: Your title says 8PM and your description says 11pm...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codehollow.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/

[TimerTrigger(0 */5 18-23 * * 1-5)]

Comment: You can make this a better answer (=useful for others) when you explain the parts in this expression