# Crontab timer to be checked every 5 minutes

Tags: .net, azure, cron

I have an Azure function that is executed every 5 minutes.

I want to be able to defined a Crontab that is checked every 5 minutes.
Sorry, my explanation might be misunderstood.

eg. Azure Function executes every 5 minutes.
Every 5 minutes the method needs to decide whether a Crontab of every 24 hours/ daily needs to run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron that executes every 5min between 6PM and 8PM during weekdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712875/cron-that-executes-every-5min-between-6pm-and-8pm-during-weekdays)

Comment: [Azure function timer trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255318/azure-function-timer-trigger)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT. I'm afraid that won't work.
I have an Azure Function that is executed every 5 minutes, within the AF I have several methods which must be run every 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 20 minutes, 24 hour, etc. I need the logic to ensure every method is executed at the correct interval.

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced In visual studio:***

[image]

***In azure portal:***

[image]

[image]

***Function.json***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

***Taken References from:***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-examples